# Source code of random() function in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, arc4random

I would like to ask if anyone of you knows where can I find the source code of random() function from Objective-C?

I found arc4random() code [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c), but cannot find simple random().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at below link. This is implementation file for `random` function.

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/stdlib/FreeBSD/random.c.auto.html